# Taylor series for $(x^n + x^m + 1)^s$

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, generating-functions

Using the trinomial theorem one gets that 
$$
[x^t](x^n + x^m + 1)^s = \sum_{\substack{i + j + k = s\\mi + nj = t}}{s \choose i,j,k}.
$$
I was wondering if one could point out to me a reference (I'm guessing in combinatorics) where this sum shows up? Any applications? Also does the sum simplify nicely (meaning a simpler identity) in special cases of $m,n$? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> One combinatorial interpretation is based upon *lattice paths* on a $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ grid with steps $(1,1),(1,0)$ and $(1,-1)$. Walks of length $n$ can be represented by the generating function
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(xy+x+xy^{-1}\right)^n\qquad\text{or}\qquad\left(1+x+x^2\right)^n
> \end{align*}
>
> Strongly connected with *[trinomial coefficients](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrinomialCoefficient.html)* are *[Motzkin numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motzkin_number)*.
>
> You may want to check this *[classic](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* from P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick for more info.

Comment: Thanks. I also found the following related paper. Seems interesting. http://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.0228.pdf

Comment: @user152169: You're welcome and thanks for the ref. Funny, this afternoon I had a closer look at table 174 of the book from Knuth, etal which is cited in section 3.1. :-)